# I am trying to stack a div below a div the height of the browser window

Tags: html, css

I want a div that is the same height as the browser window, and another div below that sits below this div.

All of my attempts fail to stack the divs and overlap them instead.

a naive implementation of what my project is attempting.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4STr/26/)

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="top">
        <p>one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <p>two</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

so the green is the whole page, the red sizes with the window and the yellow is placed under the red... you can scroll the page to see the yellow.
[image: how i want it]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/f5hmD/)**

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

### CSS

```
html,body, .top
{
    height: 100%;
}
.top
{
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}
.bottom
{
    background: yellow;
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the top div fills 100%, the other should fall in place below.

Here's an [updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shanosha/S4STr/31/).

I removed the fixed positioning and set body and html to 100% height.

```
html, body {height:100%;}
div {border:1px solid #CCC;}

.main { width:350px; height:100%; padding:5px; }
.top { height:100%; }
.bottom { margin-top:10px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is worded a bit confusing, but I gave what you asked for a shot...

Did you mean something kind of like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanhagz/S4STr/33/

```
If this isn't or it's incorrect, forgive me as I'm still learning myself...
```